# ¿Qué quiere decir "a uña de caballo"? ¿De dónde viene la expresión?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, animales

Estaba viendo el vídeo [Aitor Esteban: "Aznar hoy sería un felón"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XoPhhb3q384) en la que el diputado vasco Aitor Esteban comenta el 13 de febrero de 2019 lo siguiente (alrededor del minuto 2, sacado del [diario de sesiones del Congreso de los Diputados de España](http://www.congreso.es/portal/page/portal/Congreso/Congreso/Publicaciones/DiaSes/Pleno)):

> (...) Y enseguida a uno le viene a la cabeza el nombre de Bellido Dolfos. Algunos de más edad lo recordarán, pues era el típico traidor felón, calificado así en la historia escolar de la escuela franquista que algunos tuvimos que soportar. Aquel personaje, fingido desertor, tras haber asesinado al rey Sancho de Castilla fue **perseguido por el Cid a uña de caballo,** hasta que se refugió tras la pequeña puerta de la traición de la amurallada Zamora de la reina Urraca. No deja de ser curioso que hoy en día los zamoranos hayan decidido que el felón Bellido tenga una calle con su nombre en la ciudad y la puerta haya pasado de denominarse oficialmente portón de la traición a ser el portón de la lealtad. Al que ayer se definía como felón hoy ya es considerado como un patriota. ¡Cómo cambian las tornas dependiendo del cristal con que se mira!

A parte de lo interesante de la anécdota, me gustó la expresión *a uña de caballo*, que el DLE recoge y explica muy bien:

> [**uña**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=b72slJo)
>   `Del lat. ungŭla.`
>
> **a uña de caballo**
>   1. loc. adv. coloq. A todo el correr del caballo. *Huir, escapar, salir a uña de caballo*.
>   2. loc. adv. coloq. Dicho de actuar una persona: Liberándose de un riesgo por su cuidado y diligencia.

No soy nada experto en caballos, así que me pica la curiosidad: ¿cuál es el origen de la expresión? ¿Acaso cuando un caballo corre muy rápido apoya solamente la uña? En tal caso, ¿no sería la *pezuña*? ¿O será lo que se comenta en [la discusión *a uña de caballo* de WordReference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/a-u%C3%B1a-de-caballo.1898585/) refiriéndose a que el caballero va con tanta prisa que se aferra al caballo con las uñas al no tener tiempo de ensillar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando hablamos de animales, [uña](https://dle.rae.es/?id=b72slJo) puede ser un sinónimo de pezuña:<sup>1</sup>

> 2. f. Casco o pezuña de los animales que no tienen dedos separados.

La frase *"[huir] a uña de caballo"* es bastante vieja (aparece primero en el siglo XV<sup>3 4</sup>) y originalmente quería decir literalmente huyendo a caballo:

> A uña de *caballo*. Phraſe que explica la fuga acelerada que uno hace huyendo acaballo, por cuyos pies y ligereza ſe eſcapa de aloun peligro ò rieſgo de ſer cogido de los que le van ſiuiendo.
>
> - [*Diccionario de la lengua castellana*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=jHPnYmf-_YoC&pg=PA10&dq=%22a+u%C3%B1a+de+caballo%22) (1729)

Pero en algún momento antes del siglo XVIII, adquirió un significado más metafórico, de huir rapidamente a pie (o cualquiera otra moda):

> *A uña de caballo*, ſe pondera una vergonzoſa fuga. Para eſto es pura materialidad, que el que huye vaya montado en Mula, Pollino, Cavallo, Camello, Elefante, &c. y aun el que vaya à pie, ò ſbre una caña, como los niños.
>
> ...
>
> Tendràn los Impugnantes à buen partido tomar la fuga, y huir con preſteza, velocidad; o como ſe dice vulgar, y adverbialmente, *a uña de Cavallo*, montados en el Elefante *blanco de Siam*...
>
> - [*Demonstracion critico-apologetica de el theatro critico universal*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BqhSAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA449&dq=%22a+u%C3%B1a+de+caballo%22) (p.449-450) (1759)

Así que, se refiere simplemente a [huir sobre] un caballo galopando (ahora, metafóricamente).<sup>2</sup>

---

**Notas:**

<sup>**1.** La flor *fárfara* se llama [*uña de caballo*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=b72slJo) por la forma de sus ojas. También se conoce por [*paso/pie/uña de caballo/asno/mula*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tussilago#Nombre_com%C3%BAn) etc. Tiene nombres similares en [inglés](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tussilago), [catalán](https://ca.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pota_de_cavall) y [francés](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tussilage).</sup>

> <sup>Esta yerva es de dos maneras de la quales la una ha las hojas luenga & la otra **redondas como un pie de cavallo. & por esto de muchos es llamada uña de cavallo:**</sup>
> <sup>- *Traducción de El Libro de Propietatibus Rerum de Bartolomé Anglicus* (1494)</sup>

<sup>**2.** [*Frases, modismos, dichos y expresiones populares*](http://etiblogia.blogspot.com/2015/10/dichos-y-expresiones-populares.html) (Etimoblog: Una aproximación etimológica al léxico del Español)</sup>
<sup>**3.** *Crónica de Enrique IV de Castilla 1454-1474*</sup>
<sup>**4.** *Crónica de los Reyes Católicos* (1487 - 1488)</sup>

Comment: ¿Pero por qué se asocia ir _a uña/pezuña_ a ir rápido?

Comment: @fedorqui es solo una metáfora, los caballos son conocidos por ser rápidos, y corren en sus pies/pezuñas/uñas. Tu enlace de WordReference da unos otros ejemplos en expresiones: *"A uña de caballo, a lomos de una mula, a manos de la policía: son sinécdoques"*

Comment: Entiendo. Pero entonces, ¿por qué no decir _huir a caballo_ a secas? La definición del DLE ya dice _a todo correr_, que quiere decir yendo especialmente rápido.

Comment: @fedorqui Quizá tenga que ver con que las personas corremos casi de puntillas, como si solo apoyáramos las uñas.

Comment: @fedorqui `¿por qué no decir huir a caballo a secas?` Supongo que es un [merismo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merismo), y su belleza viene del hecho que es absolutamente innecesario. ¿Por qué decir "señoras y señores" en lugar de decir "personas"? También dicen "...en riqueza y en pobreza, en enfermedad y en salud; para amarte y cuidarte, hasta que la muerte nos separe.." en lugar de decir "siempre" Es solo una figura retórica.

Comment: Genial, ahora sí veo que se incluye el sentido metafórico de la velocidad, que me parecía inherente a la expresión. ¡Mil gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Tan sencillo como lo siguiente: Con rapidez. Y de esta forma se puede ampliar el contexto. Por ejemplo: "Resolvió el problema a uña de caballo". Por supuesto que la expresión tiene un sentido metafórico, y partiría de la sinécdoque de la parte por el todo.